# Interchanging divs in Bootstrap. Is it possible?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter, html

So my mobile site looks like this:

|A|
|B|
|C|
|D|

I want my desktop to look like this:

|A||C|
--|D|-- (Width 100%)
--|B|-- (Width 100%)

Is it possible? I tried using the push and pull functions but in no vain.

Comment: Which version of bootstrap are you using? Do you have some code to show us??

Comment: @MarcoMercuri- Version is 3.3.5. Nope, no code. I only have the website design with me and am deciding on how to structure it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6"> A </div>
     <div class="col-md-6 hidden-xs"> C </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12 visible-xs-block"> B </div>
     <div class="col-md-12 hidden-xs"> D </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12 visible-xs-block"> C </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12 visible-xs-block"> D </div>
     <div class="col-md-12 hidden-xs"> B </div>
</div>
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MaBrvZ)

Comment: Brilliant. It did not occur to me that I can simply use the hidden/visible classes. Thanks a lot. I think this will help.

Comment: Thanks, glad I could help :)